# Where can I see a list of scratch-orgs created by all the developers?

Tags: scratch-org

Our production org has the Dev-Hub featured enabled. I know there are more than a couple of scratch orgs created. I want to see the entire list and the natural place to look for them seemed to be the Dev Hub. I am not able to see them over there.

[image: scratch-orgs]

Edited to Add:
So far after talking with salesforce support, I have learned of a command that I can fire from the Powershell Terminal within Visual Studio.

`sfdx force:org:list --all`

This works *partially*, in the sense it gives me a list of my orgs but not all the active scratch orgs in the organization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to view and delete the scratch orgs from the command line, you can use a  SOQL query to list all of them, if you set your default username to an org administrator account:

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query --query='SELECT Id, Name, OrgName, CreatedDate, Description, ScratchOrg, SignupUsername FROM ActiveScratchOrg'
```

And then delete the one you don't want:

```
sfdx force:data:record:delete -s ActiveScratchOrg -i $ID
```

Answer (score 9):

This is in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_view_lex.htm):

> Log in to Dev Hub org as the System Administrator or as a user with the Salesforce DX permissions.
>
> From the App Launcher, select Active Scratch Orgs. A list of all active scratch orgs is displayed.
>
> To view more details about a scratch org, click the link in the Number column.
>
> To view the request that was used to create the scratch org, click the link in the Scratch Org Info column.

Note that you can't see the list of orgs if you don't have permission; make sure you're logged in as an administrator or have the relevant permissions.

Comment: I am the system administrator, but the app launcher is not displaying that app for me. I think I will contact salesforce support.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into an issue where The Sharing Settings for Scratch Org Info was private and I wasn't a System Admin so it wasn't overriden. Changing my role to a System Admin worked and I can see all the scratch orgs now.

Comment: As I posted earlier, I am a system administrator for this org.